# ASP.net - Does a return statement in function stop the function?

Tags: asp.net, function, loops

Given the function

```
'Returns true if no cell is > 1
Function isSolutionValid() As Boolean
    Dim rLoop As Integer
    Dim cLoop As Integer
    For cLoop = 0 To canvasCols - 1
        For rLoop = 0 To canvasRows - 1
            If canvas(cLoop, rLoop) > 1 Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

When 'return false' is fired, I'm assuming that the function is stopped at that point and there's no need for exit fors and things like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

See [Function Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s(VS.80).aspx).

> Returns control to the code that
>   called a Function, Sub, Get, Set, or
>   Operator procedure.